# Android studio gradle .pom file download error

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, jcenter

hi im from iran and we cant use gradle without proxy but now i cant use it with proxy too i dont know why i change every thing but still i cant i have my Cicsco Connection on please help me this is my gradle files
module build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.example.test.com.test"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // google support library ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'

}
```

and project gradle

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google ()
        jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google ()
        jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the errors i got

**1**:`Cause: dl.google.com:443 failed to respond`

**2**:`org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'`

**3**: `Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'`

**4**: `Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'.`

Comment: can you visit https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom in your browser? if not then get a different proxy

Comment: yes and i can download the file but i dont know copy the file on what dir @ZUNJAE

Answer (score 1):

Gradle has it's own dependency management system similar to maven. I think parts of the gradle publish plugin are backed by maven in some way (not verified). Regardless you shouldn't have to worry about that level of depth, gradle will handle it. Your problem is setting up the proxy. You just need to set some variables in $projectDir/gradle.properties, for example:

```
#http proxy setup
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

This can be used to download dependencies without proxy. If you want to use a proxy for you can use the code as below instead of above code.

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.16.2
systemProp.https.proxyHost=192.168.16.2
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
```

Proxy port and host can be changed as you want.

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem by just edit the gradle properties i added a proxy and i forgot that was my problem